# unique_ptr with custom allocator

Tags: c++, memory-management

I wrote a simple B-Tree, with `Node` is defined as:

```
class Node {
        Node* parent = nullptr;
        std::uint32_t index = 0;
        std::uint32_t height = 1;
        std::vector<T> key;
        std::vector<unique_alloc_ptr<Node>> child;
// ... details ...
};
```

where `unique_alloc_ptr` is the unique_ptr using my custom allocator.

```
template <typename T>
using unique_alloc_ptr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

template <typename T>
unique_alloc_ptr<T> make_unique_fixed(FixedAllocator<T>& alloc) {
    T* ptr = alloc.allocate(1);
    alloc.construct(ptr);

    std::function<void(T*)> deleter;
    auto deleter_ = [](T* p, FixedAllocator<T>& alloc) {
        alloc.destroy(p);
        alloc.deallocate(p, 1);
    };
    deleter = [&deleter_, &alloc](auto&& PH1) { return deleter_(std::forward<decltype(PH1)>(PH1), alloc); };
    return std::unique_ptr<T, decltype(deleter)>(ptr, deleter);
}
```

The custom allocator uses the memory pool as:

```
template <typename T>
class FixedAllocator {
    struct Chunk {
        // details ...
        unsigned char data_[blockSize_ * numBlocks_];
    };
    // details ...
    std::vector<Chunk> chunks_;
```

and my B-Tree uses the memory pool as member variable:

```
class BTree {
     class Node {
        // ...
     };
     // details ...
     FixedAllocator<Node> alloc;
     unique_alloc_ptr<Node> root;
};
```

But this gives segfault. As I guess, double free is the problem.

When lifetime of BTree ends, `FixedAllocator<Node>` is destroyed,
and its internal buffer `std::vector<Chunk>` is also destroyed.

The problem is, `unique_alloc_ptr<Node>` is also destroyed as well,
calling destructor of `std::vector<unique_alloc_ptr<Node>>` child,
which uses `FixedAllocator<Node>` as internal memory pool,
so double free problem occurs.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT**: Detailed implementation of `FixedAllocator`

```
template <typename T>
class FixedAllocator {
    struct Chunk {
        static constexpr std::size_t blockSize_ = sizeof(T);
        static constexpr unsigned char numBlocks_ = FixedAllocator::numBlocks_;

        Chunk() {
            unsigned char i = 0;
            for (unsigned char * p = &data_[0]; i != numBlocks_; p += blockSize_) {
                *p = ++i;
            }
        }

        void* allocate() {
            unsigned char* result = &data_[firstAvailableBlock_ * blockSize_];
            firstAvailableBlock_ = *result;
            --blocksAvailable_;
            return result;
        }

        void deallocate(void* p) {
            assert(p >= &data_[0]);
            auto* toRelease = static_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
            assert((toRelease - &data_[0]) % blockSize_ == 0);
            *toRelease = firstAvailableBlock_;
            firstAvailableBlock_ = static_cast<unsigned char>((toRelease - &data_[0]) / blockSize_);
            assert(firstAvailableBlock_ == (toRelease - &data_[0]) / blockSize_);
            ++blocksAvailable_;
        }

        bool hasBlock(void* p, std::size_t chunkLength) const {
            auto* pc = static_cast<unsigned char*>(p);
            return (&data_[0] <= pc) && (pc < &data_[chunkLength]);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool hasAvailable() const {
            return (blocksAvailable_ == numBlocks_);
        }

        [[nodiscard]] bool isFilled() const {
            return !blocksAvailable_;
        }

        unsigned char data_[blockSize_ * numBlocks_];
        unsigned char firstAvailableBlock_ = 0;
        unsigned char blocksAvailable_ = numBlocks_;
    };

private:
    static constexpr std::size_t blockSize_ = sizeof(T);
    static constexpr unsigned char numBlocks_ = std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::max();
    std::vector<Chunk> chunks_;
    Chunk* allocChunk_ = nullptr;
    Chunk* deallocChunk_ = nullptr;
    Chunk* emptyChunk_ = nullptr;

public:
    using value_type = T;

    void* doAllocate() {
        if (!allocChunk_ || !allocChunk_->blocksAvailable_) {
            auto it = chunks_.begin();
            for (; ; ++it) {
                if (it == chunks_.end()) {
                    chunks_.emplace_back();
                    allocChunk_ = &chunks_.back();
                    deallocChunk_ = &chunks_.front();
                    break;
                }
                if (it->blocksAvailable_) {
                    allocChunk_ = &*it;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        assert(allocChunk_);
        assert(allocChunk_->blocksAvailable_);
        return allocChunk_->allocate();
    }

    value_type* allocate(std::size_t n) {
        assert(n == 1);
        auto* p = static_cast<value_type*>(doAllocate());
        return p;
    }

    Chunk* findVicinity(void* p) const {
        assert(!chunks_.empty() && deallocChunk_);
        const std::size_t chunkLength = numBlocks_ * blockSize_;
        // bidirectional search
        Chunk* lo = deallocChunk_;
        Chunk* hi = deallocChunk_ + 1;
        const Chunk* lbound = &chunks_.front();
        const Chunk* hbound = &chunks_.back() + 1;

        if (hi == hbound) {
            hi = nullptr;
        }

        for (;;) {
            if (lo) {
                if (lo->hasBlock(p, chunkLength)) {
                    return lo;
                }
                if (lo == lbound) {
                    lo = nullptr;
                    if (!hi) {
                        break;
                    }
                } else {
                    --lo;
                }
            }
            if (hi) {
                if (hi->hasBlock(p, chunkLength)) {
                    return hi;
                }
                if (++hi == hbound) {
                    hi = nullptr;
                    if (!lo) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    void deallocate(void* p, std::size_t n) noexcept {
        assert(n == 1);
        assert(!chunks_.empty());
        assert(&chunks_.front() <= deallocChunk_);
        assert(&chunks_.back() >= deallocChunk_);
        assert(&chunks_.front() <= allocChunk_);
        assert(&chunks_.back() >= allocChunk_);

        Chunk* foundChunk = nullptr;
        const std::size_t chunkLength = numBlocks_ * blockSize_;
        if (deallocChunk_->hasBlock(p, chunkLength)) {
            foundChunk = deallocChunk_;
        } else {
            foundChunk = findVicinity(p);
        }
        assert(foundChunk && foundChunk->hasBlock(p, chunkLength));
        deallocChunk_ = foundChunk;
        // double free check
        assert(emptyChunk_ != deallocChunk_);
        assert(!deallocChunk_->hasAvailable());
        assert(!emptyChunk_ || emptyChunk_->hasAvailable());

        deallocChunk_->deallocate(p);

        if (deallocChunk_->hasAvailable()) {
            // only release chunk if there are 2 empty chunks.
            if (emptyChunk_) {
                // if last chunk is empty, just let deallocChunk_ points
                // to empty chunk, and release the last.
                // otherwise, swap two and release an empty chunk
                Chunk* lastChunk = &chunks_.back();
                if (lastChunk == deallocChunk_) {
                    deallocChunk_ = emptyChunk_;
                } else if (lastChunk != emptyChunk_) {
                    std::swap(*emptyChunk_, *lastChunk);
                }
                assert(lastChunk->hasAvailable());
                chunks_.pop_back();
                if ((allocChunk_ == lastChunk) || (allocChunk_->isFilled())) {
                    allocChunk_ = deallocChunk_;
                }

            }
            emptyChunk_ = deallocChunk_;
        }
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    void construct (value_type* p, Args&&... args) {
        std::construct_at(p, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void destroy(value_type* p) {
        std::destroy_at(p);
    }

};
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, the main issue isn't really a double-delete.  It's that you're relying on a specific destruction order: essentially requiring `BTree::root` to be destroyed before `BTree::alloc`.  There are no such guarantees by default.  In `~BTree()` you should explicitly call `root.reset()` to destroy the tree.  That way you can ensure all dependencies of `BTree::alloc` have returned their memory and there are no remaining lambdas holding onto references to your allocator.

Comment: One other thing that seems wrong is your `deleter` lambda itself -- it's capturing `deleter_` _by reference_ despite that being a local variable.  This seems very wrong.  You should capture it by value: `deleter = [deleter_, &alloc_](auto&& PH1) ...`

Comment: Members are destroyed in reverse order of declaration, so by the time the `FixedAllocator` is destroyed all of the `Node`s should already have been destroyed.  It sounds to me like there's a bug in `FixedAllocator`, but there's not enough info here to really say.  A [mcve] would help.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Added ```FixedAllocator``` code

Comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/0VNS6Mpzyy5aHalU Crash example. Ignore ```BTree``` implementation details, it worked perfectly using the default allocator

Comment: @paddy Calling ```root.reset()``` in the destructor and removing reference in that lambda still gives segfault..

Comment: You should really test your allocator in isolation.  In particular you should test re-entrant deallocations.  That is: the allocator destroys an object that contains other object which subsequently are deallocated and destroyed while still processing the first destructor.  That will reasonably emulate what's happening in your tree.  You should also be testing cases like filling and chaining multiple chunks, returning memory and reallocating within various chunks.  Test absolutely every combination and edge case you can think of.  Allocators are hard to write, and testing them is equally hard.

Comment: @paddy My IDE claims that it crashes when ```main()``` ends and ```make_unique_fixed()``` is called to delete ```root``` of ```BTree```. But variable view of ```BTree::alloc``` gives nothing. That's why it is crashing... There could be other problems as well, but at least double delete problem exists.

Comment: If you are just looking at the crash and then scratching your head, you are not sufficiently investigating.  Step through your program line by line and see what it's actually doing.  For that to be effective, you'll need to construct the absolute simplest program that reproduces the issue, to avoid wasting lots of time.  As I've already suggested, testing the allocator in isolation is recommended.  It's probably not your tree at all.

Comment: So, for example, I just did the most basic test [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ejWf3xne3) by looking at your allocator and thinking "hmm, the maximum number of blocks is 255, let's fill it".  No problem.  "now, let's allocate one more than that"...  BOOM!